# crumbling foundation wall

Tags: concrete, walls, basement, foundation

A poured concrete foundation wall is crumbling inside my basement. How concerned should I be?

Here's what it looks like at the base of the wall:

[image]

A noticeable pile of cement dust forms on the floor every few weeks.

The house is 70 years old. I run a dehumidifier, without which the basement was noticeably musty.

A home inspector (with no particular expertise with respect to foundations) saw this wall recently. He remarked on the efflorescence and poked around a bit with a screwdriver, and he didn't think there was any problem.

What should I do about this?

Answer (score 1):

If it's efflorescence, then there is not much to worry about.  If you see more than dust then it would be a cause for concern.

If you want to stop the dust then there are surface penetrating sprays such as Acquron, that should stop it.  (I am not affiliated with it but I have used it).